# Is it possible to specify a function in a bind variable using Oracle?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, oracle

When inserting data into an Oracle table from .NET is it (and how) possible to specify a function as a bind variable instead of a value?

The example below is simplistic on purpose.

For example;

```
dim oraCommand as OracleCommand = new OracleCommand("insert into dummy(dummy_string) values :value_to_insert")
oraCommand.Parameters.Add("value_to_insert", OracleDbType.VarChar, 200)
oraCommand.Parameters("value_to_insert").Value = "MY_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION(23,98,"TEST")
```

Where "MY_USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION" is a function that returns a string. I have values which can be used by an existing Oracle function to provide the value to be inserted in the DB. Since these values are time critical, I need to call the function as I am inserting the data rather than call Oracle get the data back to the client and then pass it back to Oracle.

EDIT:

I have an existing generic VB.NET function which builds insert statements from an object which contains column name, type & value for each column in the table. Igor's comment below cleared my cobwebs, and I think I've painted myself into a corner.

Comment: Why not inline the function in the insert statement and use 3 parameters for `23,98,"TEST"` respectively.

Comment: Then use this function directly in the INSERT query rather than the bind variable, for examle: `Insert into dummy(dummy_string) values ( my_super_function )`. Just like any other Oracle's functions, for example SYSDATE - `Insert into dummy(dummy_string) values ( sysdate )` .

Comment: Igor, that is the solution. Unfortunately difficult for me to implement with the existing code. I have a generalized VB.NET function that handles inserts based on passing an object with all of the fields & values.

Comment: In any case, this is not "using Oracle". The assignment statement will assign a value to "value_to_insert" regardless of how the right-had side is evaluated (whether it is a literal value, the result of a simple computation, or the return value from a function). What is passed to Oracle is the bind variable and its value; HOW the value is assigned to the variable is completely external to Oracle, it seems to be done in VB.NET (or whatever your code is).